# Delete parpool object behaviour on SLURM cluster

Tags: matlab, hpc, slurm

I am running Matlab R2016b on a SLURM cluster using MDCS toolbox. I open a parallel pool on the cluster with 10 Nodes and perform my computations without any errors as expected. The problem is when the script ends or I close the parallel pool, the workers that were requested from the cluster are not relinquished back and run to max-time requested from the cluster. Each time I manually cancel the jobs on the cluster. It seems to me that there should be a smarter way to close the jobs without manually checking. In short, I am looking for a way to close the cluster nodes when I delete parpool object on the host node. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you  delete the `parpool` object, it is intended that the SLURM job running on the cluster is terminated. If this isn't happening, then something is going wrong with the cluster integration scripts you're using. You might well need to contact MathWorks support to resolve this.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing to the cluster integration scripts. I have requested a reply from mathworks support too.

Comment: @Edric Thanks for pointing in right direction. I looked at the deleteJobFcn and it seems like the job is 'not' deleted when the job state is finished or failed - which doesn't make any sense to me. So I changed the condition to 'delete' when finished or failed. That fixed it for me. Thanks!